# simple statistics of aggregated posterior data after ensemble data assimilation

Tags: variance, ensemble-learning, aggregation

I have $N$ "4-dimensional" arrays $(x,y,t,c)_{i=1:N}$ containing greenhouse gas emission data, where

- $(x,y)$ are the spatial coordinates
- $t$ is the time coordinate (discrete time points)
- $c$ is the "category", that indicates the source of the emissions, e.g., some industrial process.

Each array $i$ is a sample of my (unknown) Bayesian posterior distribution. For simplicity, we can assume that there is no correlation between data from different categories or at different times.

I want to compute the (gridded) ensemble mean and variance for the emissions aggregated over time and category. What would be the best way to do so?

1. aggregate each array over time & category, then compute the statistics

OR

2. compute the mean/variance of the original arrays, then aggregate the statistics over time & category (not sure how I can do that for the variances)